# why does this js RegExp test return true?

Tags: javascript

```
var result = new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\s\.]").test("hello world.")
```

Shouldn't the `\s` catch the space?  If I remove the whitespace between `hello` and `world` it evaluates correctly.

Comment: Since the pattern is in `""`, you have to double the backslashes --- `\\s` etc.

Comment: To clarify, any string passed through the RegExp constructor requires backslashes so single quotes also returns true (maybe that was implied but thought I'd clarify anyways). Worth noting that JavaScript understands regex itself so you can do `new RegExp(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\s\.]/).test("hello world.")` and it works.